# Show that if $W_1$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ and if there exists a unique vector space $W_2$ such that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ then $V=W_1.$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:** Show that if $W_1$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ and if there exists a unique vector space $W_2$ such that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ then $V=W_1.$

I tried to think about this problem for a while and I feel quite puzzled. I was first thinking to show that $W_2=\{0\}$ and thus we would have that $V=W_1\oplus \{0\}=W_1,$ but this path seems to be difficult.

The author of the problem begins by considering the basis of $V$ as follows $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,....,\alpha_m,\alpha_{m+1},...,\alpha_n\}.$ And then says that if $V\not =W_1$ we have that $\dim W_1<\dim V.$ He then says that let $\dim W_1=m$ with the basis elements of $W_1$ being $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,....,\alpha_m\}.$ Then he says that let $W_2=\text{Span}\{\alpha_{m+1},...,\alpha_n\}$ and let $W_3=\text{Span}\{\alpha_1+\alpha_{m+1},...,\alpha_n\}.$ He then argues that $V=W_1\oplus W_2=W_1\oplus W_3,$ but $W_2\not =W_3.$

However, I am not convinced by the last part. I think that $\dim W_2=\dim W_3=n-m$ and thus $W_2=W_3.$ Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Yes, $\dim W_2=\dim W_3$, but that does not make $W_2=W_3$.

Comment: The claim in the problem is false. Consider $W_1=0$ in $V\ne 0$.

Comment: Why is there a downvote? This is not my problem, it appeared in a textbook. What mistake have I made?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen what if we consider proper subspaces?